# Prove an identity with a given commutator realation

Tags: operator-theory

Suppose operators $A,B$ satisfiy $[A,B]=aB$ where $a$ is a constant, how to show
$$e^{iAt}Be^{-iAt}=e^{iat}B$$ where $t$ is a real constant?

I tried directly expanding $e^{iAt}$ into power series and relate the series back to the commutator, but cannot produce the expected result.
Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: What did you get when you tried expanding the series? Did you try showing $e^{iAt} B = e^{iat} B e^{iAt}$, to avoid having to product two series?

Comment: I was stuck exactly on the two series... but the expression you show gives me a hint on how to proceed, thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you work it out in the end?

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes, and I also see that it is an application of one form HCB formula.